# How do I display product counts grouping by product type and month?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with 4 columns, say ProductName, ProductType, ProductProductionStartDate, ProductProductionCompleteDate.

What I need to do is display the product count for each product type for 12 months.

How do I do it ?

My below is my code :

```
var model = context.Projects
    .Where(p => (p.ProductProductionStartDate > sdt && p.ProductProductionStartDate <= edt) && (p.ProductProductionCompleteDate != null))
    .GroupBy(p => new
    {
        Month = p.ProductProductionStartDate.HasValue ? p.ProductProductionStartDate.Value.Month : 0,
        Year = p.ProductProductionStartDate.HasValue ? p.ProductProductionStartDate.Value.Year : 0,
        productType = p.ProductType
    })
   .Select(g => new Dashmain
   {
       ProductType = g.Key.StoreType,
       Month = g.Key.Month,
       Year = g.Key.Year,
       Total = g.Count()
   })
   .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
   .ThenBy(a => a.Month)
   .ToList();
```

[image: this is how I want to display the result]

Comment: Can you show an example of in and output?

Comment: it does not throw the error. It works but it is not how I do want to visualize data in dashboard table. It returns list like in this way { [feb,10],[feb,20], [feb,5]},  { [March,10],[March,20],[March,5]}. I want to show the data in this way {[Feb, 10,20,5], [March,10,20,5]} number in the example is Product count by type for each month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to show the data in this way `{[Feb, 10,20,5], [March,10,20,5]}`

You need to nest the `GroupBy` on the type, like this:

```
var model = context.Projects
    .Where(p => (p.ProductProductionStartDate > sdt && p.ProductProductionStartDate <= edt) && (p.ProductProductionCompleteDate != null))
    .GroupBy(p => new
    {
        Month = p.ProductProductionStartDate.HasValue ? p.ProductProductionStartDate.Value.Month : 0,
        Year = p.ProductProductionStartDate.HasValue ? p.ProductProductionStartDate.Value.Year : 0
    })
   .Select(g => new Dashmain
   {
       Month = g.Key.Month,
       Year = g.Key.Year,
       Totals = g.GroupBy(gg => gg.StoreType).OrderBy(gg => gg.Key).Select(gg => gg.Count()).ToList()
   })
   .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
   .ThenBy(a => a.Month)
   .ToList();
```

Note that this approach has a limitation: months that have zero products of a certain category would have no data at all. To deal with this problem you could build a helper method that adds zeros for products of missing types.